# TweenAnimationBuilder is not repeating properly Flutter

Tags: flutter, animation, builder, tween

I have a a basic `TweenAnimationBuilder` to animate a `CircularProgressIndicator` which I want to repeat on click or onEnd animation :

```
           Consumer<MyProvider>(
                builder: (context, model, child) {
                  print("Reload");
                  return TweenAnimationBuilder<double>(
                    tween: Tween<double>(begin: 1, end: 0),
                    duration: Duration(seconds: 10),
                    onEnd: () {
                      myProvider.notify();
                    },
                    builder: (context, value, _) {
                      print("progress : " + value.toString());
                      return CircularProgressIndicator(
                        value: value,
                        strokeWidth: 2,
                        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                        valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation(Colors.white),
                      );
                    },
                  );
                },
              ),
```

I'm using a `Provider` to notify change and repeat the animation instead of `setState()`.
The problem also occurs by calling `setState()`

When the `Widget` is reloaded the animation is restarted with 0.0 instead of repeat it.

Here is the logging output :

```
I/flutter (14250): progress : 0.011378200000000005
I/flutter (14250): progress : 0.008043799999999934
I/flutter (14250): progress : 0.004709100000000022
I/flutter (14250): progress : 0.0013756000000000324
I/flutter (14250): Reload
I/flutter (14250): progress : 0.0
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: did you find an answer or a solution

Comment: @ArslanKaleem I workaround this by using a simple loop with ```AnimationController```  . But this issue is still not resolved